# How to insert file directory

Tags: c#, directory, itext

I made a program with iTextSharp which allows the user to click on a button to choose a file and do the main function with the second button.
Now I want to make a button which will replace this function in the second button:

```
using (Stream dest = File.Create(@"L:\Users\user\Documents\PDFnummerieren\PDF.pdf"))
```

I want to make a third button which will get the chosen location by the user, not a  given location which is not changeable.

**The whole Code:**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(theFile) || !File.Exists(theFile))
            return;
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(theFile);
        iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12,
 iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        using (Stream source = File.OpenRead(theFile))
        using (Stream dest = File.Create(theCFile))
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, dest))
            {
                int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                {
                    ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        new Phrase(i.ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

         private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            theFile = FD.FileName;
    }
    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) ;

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? You've correctly identified OpenFileDialog as the way to ask the user for a folder.

Comment: File.Create saves the file as PDF.pdf in the given direction. It doesnt ask the user where it should be saved. It just asks where the file is to convert

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to select a folder location.

You can combine the output folder and filename using `Path.Combine(selectedFolder, filename)` and place that in the `using` statement.

Code for saving the selected output folder:

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string selectedPath = FD.SelectedPath;
        theCFile = Path.Combine(selectedPath, theFile)
    }
}
```

Comment: but I can do ´savedFile = FD.FileName;´ because the user would need to click on a other PDF to replace it. I want him to just choose a directory and save it then as the name before.

Comment: You can use the [FolderBrowserDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2). I will update my answer

Comment: It says: 
An empty path is forbidden.

Comment: Can you update your starting post with your current code so I can take a look?

Comment: The process can not access the file "..." because it is being used by another process.

Comment: using (Stream dest = File.Create(theCFile)) is marked

Comment: Are you by chance trying to write to the same file as you are reading from? Do you have the file opened in another program?